# importing Error for xarray returns "DLL load failed while importing defs"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray, pygmt

I have tried almost all the available resources including uninstalling and re-installing to fix this issue but no luck so far.
Can I have your expert advice to fix this issue...

```
  !pip install xarray

Requirement already satisfied: xarray in c:\users\computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in c:\users\computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from xarray) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0 in c:\users\computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from xarray) (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.4 in c:\users\computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from xarray) (58.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.0->xarray) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.0->xarray) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\computer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=1.0->xarray) (1.16.0)

                import xarray as xr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-b027d314c3e9> in <module>
----> 1 import xarray as xr

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\__init__.py in <module>
      1 import pkg_resources
      2 
----> 3 from . import testing, tutorial, ufuncs
      4 from .backends.api import (
      5     load_dataarray,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\tutorial.py in <module>
     11 import numpy as np
     12 
---> 13 from .backends.api import open_dataset as _open_dataset
     14 from .backends.rasterio_ import open_rasterio as _open_rasterio
     15 from .core.dataarray import DataArray

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\__init__.py in <module>



7 from .common import AbstractDataStore, BackendArray, BackendEntrypoint

          8 from .file_manager import CachingFileManager, DummyFileManager, FileManager
    ----> 9 from .h5netcdf_ import H5NetCDFStore
         10 from .memory import InMemoryDataStore
         11 from .netCDF4_ import NetCDF4DataStore

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\h5netcdf_.py in <module>
     33 
     34 try:
---> 35     import h5netcdf
     36 
     37     has_h5netcdf = True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5netcdf\__init__.py in <module>
      6 HDF5 files via h5py, without using the Unidata netCDF library.
      7 """
----> 8 from .core import CompatibilityError, File, Group, Variable, __version__  # noqa

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5netcdf\core.py in <module>
      7 from distutils.version import LooseVersion
      8 
----> 9 import h5py
     10 import numpy as np
     11 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py in <module>
     31         raise
     32 
---> 33 from . import version
     34 
     35 if version.hdf5_version_tuple != version.hdf5_built_version_tuple:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\h5py\version.py in <module>
     13 
     14 from collections import namedtuple
---> 15 from . import h5 as _h5
     16 import sys
     17 import numpy

h5py\h5.pyx in init h5py.h5()

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing defs: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: "I have tried almost all the available resources" – can you list other things you've tried? Just to make sure no one's doubling your efforts :)

Comment: When I say available resources, I mean stack overflow solutions with related tag #array #python-array, #xarray. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the python environment and even wiped out the Anaconda that was used to install this module. I hope I am bit clear this time.